# Open a file dialog over ssh and ftp to save a file remotely in QT

Tags: c++, qt, ssh, ftp

I want to save a file to a network server. Currently, I need to first save it locally, and then copy it to the server. The server supports ssh and ftp.

I would like instead to operate all directories and files in my GUI as if they were local paths, as follows:

1. Connect to the server, using ssh or ftp or tftp.
2. Then I click the `get file` button.
3. A `FileDialog` shows, displaying a drop-down list of all servers, while also including the local path.
4. When I choose a server, then list the server's directory, I can operate it as a local directory.

I know I can use `QFileDialog` in my QT project to open a file from local disk or save it, but can it do this?

Is there any way, when saving a file, to choose either to put it in the server or the local directory?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: I don't understand, are you asking for a code sample that will solve your task? If YES - then your question is offtopic. If NO - then you should provide a SSCCE of your attempts of solving your problem.

Comment: I want it work both in Linux and Windows. NO, I just want to get a way . not code, some advice? I think it's hard or bad way to write a new Fileopendialog totally. thanks